# Cast LINQ Function Result to Domain Object

Tags: c#, linq, function, casting

I have a table valued function to perform full text search on SQL server.

The result type of my full text search function in LINQ is a special autogenerated type which includes KEY and RANK in addition to my regular domain object properties.

So, if my regular domain object is PERSONS (with properties FirstName, LastName etc.), I also have a result object PERSONS_FTSResult with the same properties + KEY and RANK.

Is there an easy way to cast it back to PERSONS?

Comment: Just curious, why don't you just select a PERSON from the result of your query, i.e <Linq query>, then Select new PERSON {//assignproperties};

Comment: Can you give me some sample code please?

Comment: Robaticus posted my intent, you essentially select a new anonymous type.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you do something like this:

```
var x = from data in searchResults
        select new {
            key = data.Key,
            rank = data.Rank,
            person = new Person { firstName = data.FirstName }
                    };

Person p = x.First().person;
```

I apologize if a bit of the syntax is bad, but I'm playing Eve Online, not coding right now.

:)

Comment: Sorry I can't figure this out. Can you check this code please?

Comment: You said that your search results would contain all of the members of Person, plus Key and Rank.  The LINQ above selects a new anonymous type that consists of all of the data, and initializes it appropriately. 

The first two things it puts in the type are key, and rank.  Then it creates a new instance of Person, and initialize it with the result set. 

Looking at it, I did notice one issue, the right hand side of the assignment should have the word "data" prepended to them.  I'll edit.